# Retrieve data in the ionic between pages

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage, cross-platform

I have a question about ionic, I store data on the first page as input data from the user including the location, so how I can retrieve my data on the second page, and this is my code for the first page (typescript code)

```js
export class HomePage {

  //tags: Tag[];
  locations :UserLocation[]; 
  tag: string;
  locationName: string;
  recipientName: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  address: string;
  showTagList: boolean; 
  showTagButtonText: string; 

  constructor(public router:Router,private sanitizer:DomSanitizer, private storage: Storage,private geolocation: Geolocation, private nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder) {
    //this.tags = [];
    this.locations = []; 

  }
  
  async ngOnInit()
   {
    await this.storage.create();
    this.retrieveList();
  }

  async retrieveList()
   {
    //this.tags = await this.storage.get("tags");
    this.locations = await this.storage.get("locations"); 
  }

 getMyLocation()
 {
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then( data => this.getLocationDetails(data)); 
 }
 getLocationDetails(location: GeolocationPosition)
 {
   let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
     useLocale: true,
     maxResults: 5
   };
   this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude, options).then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => this.handleLocation(location,result)); 
 }
 handleLocation(location: GeolocationPosition,result:NativeGeocoderResult[])
 {
   if(this.locations == null)
     this.locations = [];
   let mylocation: UserLocation = new UserLocation(this.address,this.phoneNumber,this.recipientName ,this.locationName,location,this.sanitizer,result);
   this.locations.push(mylocation); 
   this.storage.set("locations",this.locations);
   

 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the second page, you can simply retrieve it the same way you did for the first page :

```
this.locations = await this.storage.get("locations");
```

Be aware that the get will return null/undefined on first call on HomePage, because you haven't saved it already. To prevent an error when you will try to use this array, you can add a fallback value :

```
this.locations = (await this.storage.get("locations")) || [];
```

Then, if not set, you would have an empty array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Years of experince with Ionic taught me not to use localStorage to store data
between pages. Issues with this method are as follows:

1. Data that is no longer relevant is passed between pages.
2. It becomes tedious to cleanup, clear storage and insert new data as more pages are added.
3. Difficult to work with arrays with local storage.

If you want to just send simple data IDs or short strings between pages, i would suggest you to use paramap: https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/

If you want to transfer more complex data (arrays) between pages / components, i would suggest you to use Input / Outputs: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Else you can create a service and initialize getters / setters accordingly as you switch between pages.